# Text inside bootstrap list group `a` not aligning to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I was trying to align a part of the text to right and rest to left end of bootstraplist group, but everything always align to left,
[I was trying to make text 'Drago' to left end, and the emoji to the left end of each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5dkb.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="list-group shadow">
{% for newsletter in newsletter_list %}

    <a href="{{newsletter.slug}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <span class="float-left"></span>
            <span class="float-right">Drago</span>
        </a>
 
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` on your `a` elements. This will `pull` the `text` the to right and will be `responsive` in the *modern browsers* as well.

I will **not** recemend using `float-right` or `float-left` - Using flex classes is way much better for responsiveness.

**Demo:**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="list-group shadow">
        <a href="{{newsletter.slug}}" class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action">
          <span class=""></span> 
          <span class="">Drago</span> 
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group shadow">
        <a href="{{newsletter.slug}}" class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action">
          <span class=""></span>. 
          <span class="">Drago</span> 
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @abhimt97 Glad to hear that. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try using class="pull-left" instead of class="float-left"

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="list-group shadow">
{% for newsletter in newsletter_list %}

    <a href="{{newsletter.slug}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <span class="pull-left"></span>
            <span class="pull-right">Drago</span>
        </a>
 
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```